# I want to have the Fibonacci sequence returned with commas between the numbers

Tags: python

```
def get_fibonacci_sequence(num: int) -> str:
    '''
    Function to return string with fibonacci sequence
    
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(0)
    ''
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(1)
    '0'
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(9)
    '0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21'
    '''
    
    first_term = 0
    second_term = 1
    nth_term = 0
    result = ''
    
    for sequence in range(num):
        result += str(first_term)
        nth_term = first_term + second_term
        first_term = second_term
        second_term = nth_term
    return(result)
```

I tried adding (+ ',') in the loop where I convert the numbers to a string and it works but not the way I want it to.

'0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,'

I want to get rid of the comma after 21

Answer (score 4):

> I want to get rid of the [trailing] comma

```
    result = ''
    
    for sequence in range(num):
        result += str(first_term)
```

The standard idiom is to use `.join( ... )`:

```
    result = []
    
    for sequence in range(num):
        result.append(first_term)
    ...
    return ', '.join(map(str, result))
```

That way you only get `,` comma **between** the list elements.

Comment: Do we really need the `map` here, if `result` is already defined as a list?

Comment: @icedwater, well, we're gonna want to turn `int` into `str` at some point. You could choose to `.append(str(first_term))` if you're allergic to `map`. But that impressed me as a less logical datastructure than having a sequence of integers.

Answer (score 2):

> *"... I want to get rid of the comma after 21"*

Append the values to a *list*, rather than a *string*.

And then, return the value of a *str.join* call.

```py
first_term = 0
second_term = 1
nth_term = 0
result = []

for sequence in range(num):
    result.append(str(first_term))
    nth_term = first_term + second_term
    first_term = second_term
    second_term = nth_term
return ','.join(result)
```

Output

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your loop slightly to avoid adding a comma after the last number. You can achieve this by checking if you're at the last iteration of the loop. Here's an updated version of your function:

```
def get_fibonacci_sequence(num: int) -> str:
        '''
        Function to return string with Fibonacci sequence
        
        >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(0)
        ''
        >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(1)
        '0'
        >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(9)
        '0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21'
        '''
        
        if num <= 0:
            return ''  # Return an empty string for non-positive input
        
        first_term = 0
        second_term = 1
        nth_term = 0
        result = ''
        
        for sequence in range(num):
            result += str(first_term)
            if sequence < num - 1:  # Check if it's not the last iteration
                result += ','
            nth_term = first_term + second_term
            first_term = second_term
            second_term = nth_term
            
        return result
    
    # Test cases
    print(get_fibonacci_sequence(0))  # Should print ''
    print(get_fibonacci_sequence(1))  # Should print '0'
    print(get_fibonacci_sequence(9))  # Should print '0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list first if you want: `result = []`. Then add the new numbers to the list: `result.append(nth_term)`. At the end you convert the list to a `str`, and you remove the brackets: `result_string = str(result)[1:-1]`.

Comment: The answer of @J_H is almost the same, but I like his solution more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in this way by adding an if condition:

```
def get_fibonacci_sequence(num: int) -> str:
    '''
    Function to return string with fibonacci sequence
    
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(0)
    ''
    >>> get_fibonnaci_sequence(1)
    '0"
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(9)
    '0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21'
    '''
    
    first_term = 0
    second_term = 1
    nth_term = 0
    result = ''
    
    for sequence in range(num):
        result += str(first_term)
        nth_term = first_term + second_term
        first_term = second_term
        second_term = nth_term
        if sequence!=num-1:   #add condition
            result+=','
    return(result)
print(get_fibonacci_sequence(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the numbers to one string, individually convert them to strings and add the number to a list, which would look like this: `["0","1",1","2","3",5","8","1","21"]`

Once you are done, simply use result.join(",") and you have a string that would look like "0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21"

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is the easiest way to solve your problem :**

```
def get_fibonacci_sequence(num: int) -> str:
    '''
    Function to return string with fibonacci sequence
    
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(0)
    ''
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(1)
    '0'
    >>> get_fibonacci_sequence(9)
    '0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21'
    '''
    
    first_term = 0
    second_term = 1
    nth_term = 0
    result = ''
    
for i in range(num):
    result += str(first_term)
    if i < num - 1:
        result += ','
    nth_term = first_term + second_term
    first_term = second_term
    second_term = nth_term

return result
```

**The for loop calculates and appends the subsequent Fibonacci number, beginning with the third Fibonacci number, to the result string each time iteration 'num - 2' is performed.**

## Test cases

```
print(get_fibonacci_sequence(0))  # Output: ''
print(get_fibonacci_sequence(1))  # Output: '0'
print(get_fibonacci_sequence(5))  # Output: '0,1,1,2,3'
print(get_fibonacci_sequence(9))  # Output: '0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the comma separation in the *print()* call like this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1

    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        b, a = a+b, b

print(*fibonacci(9), sep=',')
```

**Output:**

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21
```

If you need to keep the formatted values as a string then:

```
as_string = ','.join(map(str, fibonacci(9)))
```